# Using TabBar like filter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i'm trying to make a Tabbar that appear in a new page when the search icon in pressed. The code works fine but i don't know how to implement this tabbar. I want to use the tabbar for splitting the search info, each icon has to show only specific info.

I guess each icon has a specific list?

**This is my search_tool.dart**  *this appear when the icon button at the main page is pressed*

**[EDIT]** Now the result is shown correctly, but when I press the search box to write the error message contained in buildSuggestion always appears, instead it should only show the list with the relative records and if something not belonging to that category is searched then it must give the error message

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:solaris/lista_data.dart';
import 'constants.dart';

class LinkItemsSearch extends SearchDelegate<LinkItem>{
  @override
  PreferredSizeWidget buildBottom(BuildContext context) {

    return PreferredSize(
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    query = 'Apps';
                    this.showResults(context);
                  },
                  child: Text('Apps'),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    query = 'Movies';
                    this.showResults(context);
                  },
                  child: Text('Movies'),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    query = 'Games';
                    this.showResults(context);
                  },
                  child: Text('Games'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(60),
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.clear),onPressed: () { query=""; },)];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(onPressed: () { Navigator.pop(context); }, icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),);
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {

    var mylist = loadLinkItem().where((p) => p.description.contains(query)).toList();

    return Container(
      color: blue,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: mylist.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
            final LinkItem listitem = mylist[index];
            return Container(
              color: blue,
              child: ListTile(
                title:InkWell(
                  onTap: () { Navigator.pushReplacement(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => listitem.link)); },
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget> [
                      Text(listitem.title, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      Text(listitem.description, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 14),),
                      Divider(color: white,),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {

        final mylist = query.isEmpty? loadLinkItem():loadLinkItem().where((p) => p.description.contains(RegExp(query, caseSensitive: false))).toList();

    return mylist.isEmpty?
    Container(
      color: red,
      child: Center(child: Text('No Result Found . . .', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20,))),
    ):Container(
      color: blue,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: mylist.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
            final LinkItem listitem = mylist[index];
            return Container(
              color: blue,
              child: ListTile(onTap: (){ showResults(context);},
                title:InkWell(
                  onTap: () { Navigator.pushReplacement(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => listitem.link)); },
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget> [
                      Text(listitem.title, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      Text(listitem.description, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 14),),
                      Divider(color: white,),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

**Search icon**

```
IconButton(onPressed:(){
   showSearch(context: context, delegate: LinkItemsSearch());
}, icon: Icon(Icons.search),),
```

**List**

```
class LinkItem{
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final link;
  LinkItem({
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.link,
});
}

List<LinkItem> loadLinkItem(){
  var link = <LinkItem>[
    LinkItem(
        title: 'Title1',
        description: 'Apps',
        link: Title1(),
    ),LinkItem(
        title: 'Title2',
        description: 'Movies',
        link: Title2(),
    ),LinkItem(
        title: 'Title3',
        description: 'Games',
        link: Title3(),
    ),
  ];
  return link;
}
```

Comment: You can override `buildBottom` method which is a type of `PreferredSizeWidget`, but not sure if that would work in your case. Can you provide bit more details or even better some UI how it should look like and I can try to help?

Comment: Of course, the first image is what I get, the second is what I want. When I click on the first button it has to show me only the things related to that button and not also those of the other buttons and the other way around. Also I don't know how to change the gray part at the top to the default blue. Link: https://imgur.com/a/z8GQ4v2

Comment: Ok, got it. Let me create an example for you, I'll provide it as a new answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIX

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:solaris/lista_data.dart';
import 'constants.dart';

class LinkItemsSearch extends SearchDelegate<LinkItem>{
  @override
  PreferredSizeWidget buildBottom(BuildContext context) {

    return PreferredSize(
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    query = 'Apps';
                    this.showResults(context);
                  },
                  child: Text('Apps'),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    query = 'Movies';
                    this.showResults(context);
                  },
                  child: Text('Movies'),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    query = 'Games';
                    this.showResults(context);
                  },
                  child: Text('Games'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(60),
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.clear),onPressed: () { query=""; },)];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(onPressed: () { Navigator.pop(context); }, icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),);
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {

    var mylist = loadLinkItem().where((p) => p.description.contains(query)).toList();

    return Container(
      color: blue,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: mylist.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
            final LinkItem listitem = mylist[index];
            return Container(
              color: blue,
              child: ListTile(
                title:InkWell(
                  onTap: () { Navigator.pushReplacement(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => listitem.link)); },
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget> [
                      Text(listitem.title, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      Text(listitem.description, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 14),),
                      Divider(color: white,),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final mylist = query.isEmpty? loadLinkItem():loadLinkItem().where((p) => p.description.contains(RegExp(query, caseSensitive: false))).toList();
    return mylist.isEmpty?
    Container(
      color: red,
      child: Center(child: Text('No Result Found . . .', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20,))),
    ):Container(
      color: blue,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: mylist.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
            final LinkItem listitem = mylist[index];
            return Container(
              color: blue,
              child: ListTile(onTap: (){ showResults(context);},
                title:InkWell(
                  onTap: () { Navigator.pushReplacement(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => listitem.link)); },
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget> [
                      Text(listitem.title, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      Text(listitem.description, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 14),),
                      Divider(color: white,),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `buildBottom` method in your `LinkItemsSearch`:

```
@override
PreferredSizeWidget buildBottom(BuildContext context) {
  return PreferredSize(
    child: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  query = 'Apps';

                  mylist = loadLinkItem()
                      .where((p) => p.description.contains(query))
                      .toList();

                  this.showResults(context);
                },
                child: Text('Apps'),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  query = 'Movies';

                  mylist = loadLinkItem()
                      .where((p) => p.description.contains(query))
                      .toList();

                  this.showResults(context);
                },
                child: Text('Movies'),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  query = 'Games';

                  mylist = loadLinkItem()
                      .where((p) => p.description.contains(query))
                      .toList();

                  this.showResults(context);
                },
                child: Text('Games'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(60),
  );
}
```

For this to work, you have to create `myList` on the top of your `LinkItemsSearch` and reuse it when filtering everywhere.
Also, I just updated `loadLinkItem` method to have some input for filtering:

```
List<LinkItem> loadLinkItem() {
  var link = <LinkItem>[
    LinkItem(
      title: 'Title1',
      description: 'Movies',
      link: '',
    ),
    LinkItem(
      title: 'Title2',
      description: 'Games',
      link: '',
    ),
    LinkItem(
      title: 'Title3',
      description: 'Apps',
      link: '',
    ),
  ];
  return link;
}
```

Of course, I have not completely matched your style, so I did not style buttons as you need it, you might higher bottom bar than 60 as I used. I also have not attached any on press handlers since I am not sure what should they do, but it looks as it is expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/osUkt.png

I wrapped them with a `Column` and `SingleChildScrollView` in case you have more of those items and they need to be scrollable: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyWVX.png

You can even add some conditions in cases when you don't need this bottom bar to be displayed and in that case, you can just return `null` from the `buildBottom` method.

Comment: it's nice, don't worry about the style, but i didn't understand how to show things when a specific button is clicked. The code now always shows the 3 lines regardless of which button is pressed, how can i fix that?

Comment: For example, if I press App only the list Title1, Title2 etc. will appear, if I press Movies only the list Movies1, Movies2 etc. will appear and so on.

Comment: I see, I'll update my answer a bit to provide answer to this too.

Comment: Should be something close to what you need now, right?

Comment: yes it's close but a little bit strange btw

Comment: I mean when i click on "App" the query must be empty and below it must appear Title3 and future TitleN which will be inserted

Comment: Okay, got it. I'll try to sort it out.

Comment: Ok, the probles is in buildResult, i fixed that but when i'm in a category and i want to search a specific stuff appears No Result Found due for suggestion, how can i fix that?